# I'm sure "textFiled.text!" contains a value. Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFiled: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func pressDoneButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSecondVC", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showSecondVC" {
            let secondVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            secondVC.textLabel.text = textFiled.text!
        }
    }

}
```

> The error is : thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while
>   unwrapping an Optional value

But I'm sure `textFiled.text!` contains a value.

Why the error comes?

Comment: Don't assign text directly to another view controller. use `viewWillAppear` method of other class for that. and just pass the data to another view controller via object.

Comment: Did you connect outlet IB to the textFiled?

Comment: Check that textFiled (sic) is connected as an outlet correctly.

Comment: secondVC.textLabel.text is UILabel in the SecondViewController. I can pass data to a String to the SecondViewController. i.e. textInSecondView can revive the textFiled.text!. But when I type  'secondVC.textLabel.text = textFiled.text!" the error comes again.

Comment: It won't work with `'secondVC.textLabel.text = textFiled.text!`

Comment: textFiled is connected as an outlet correctly.

Comment: Yes. When "'secondVC.textLabel.text" comes, it'll crash.

Comment: pass it like `secondVC.yourString = textFiled.text!` and in `SecondViewController` declare `var yourString: String?` and in `SecondViewController` in `viewWillAppear` set `textLabel.text = yourString`

Comment: When reviewing the duplicate, be sure to see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49818897/1226963

Comment: That's cool. Finally...I find the light in the dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do,

```
secondVC.textLabel.text = textFiled.text!
```

You are right about `textFiled.text!` does have value and it is not nil here. But `secondVC.textLabel` is nil because `secondVC` is not loaded yet and all the outlets of a view-controller will be nil before it loads.

You should pass `textFiled.text!` to some variable and assign this to text-field in `viewDidLoad` method of `SecondViewController`.